# (403) Insufficient Permission, for sending email on gmail api

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, send, http-status-code-403

I'm able to retrieve an email with authentication for reading the google api. I followed the [quick start guid](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php), and am able to read email messages after setting up a client and linking it to a `client_secret.json` file.

What I have working so far is the following:

```
<?php
require 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-api-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
//$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

//$results = $service->users_messages->get('denverwebsiterepair@gmail.com', '14eadd821012b3ed');
$optParams['maxResults'] = 5; 
$optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; 
$messages= $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $optParams); 
$list = $messages->getMessages(); 
$messageId = $list[0]->getId(); 

$optParamsGet = []; 
$optParamsGet['format'] = 'full'; 
$message = $service->users_messages->get('me', $messageId, $optParamsGet); 
$messagePayload = $message->getPayload(); 
$headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders(); 
$part = $message->getPayload()->getParts(); 

$body = $part[0]['body']; 
$rawData = $body->data; 
$decodeMessage = base64_decode($rawData); 

// THIS IS THE MESSAGE BODY I CAN GET

echo $decodeMessage;
```

What puzzles me is that when I try the following to try to send mail, per the google instructions, I get the error:

```
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send: (403) Insufficient Permission
```

All I did was add a change to the bottom:

```
<?php
require 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-api-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();

//------------ MY CHANGES HERE ---------------

$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
//$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

try {
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message(); 
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode("THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE"), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
    $msg->setRaw($mime); 
    $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg); 
    echo "OK";   
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(); 

}
```

EDIT: I realized that my `Google_Service_Gmail` scope was set to `READ_ONLY`. I tried changing this to `MAIL_GOOGLE_COM` per the [api source on line 34](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php), but still got the error.

Comment: So I guess it's just another lost cause, mystery in the misty fog of modern software development.

Comment: The quick start guide you linked to was for Google Drive. Try following the [Gmail quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).

Answer (score 5):

Change the the scope to: GMAIL_COMPOSE instead to MAIL_GOOGLE_COM and then try to reconnect through Google API so it get the permission again. You can also add multiple scope in the scopes array.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Forget to reconnect through Google API by re generating the credentials after deleting the old one on google developer console, after updating the scope in the code as per required.